# Permissions issues when starting rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux

I am trying to start a rails application on Ubuntu. Now I can only start my server with `sudo rails s` otherwise I get this

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.1.7.6 application starting in development 
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /home/maxycle/code/collaborasound/log/development.log exists and is writable (ie, make it writable for user and group: chmod 0664 /home/maxycle/code/collaborasound/log/development.log). The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.
Exiting
/var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:433:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /home/maxycle/code/collaborasound/tmp/pids/server.pid (Errno::EACCES)
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:433:in `open'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:433:in `write_pid'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:317:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:39:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:144:in `block in perform'
    from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `perform'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor/command.rb:28:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor.rb:527:in `dispatch'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7.6/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7.6/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.17.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.17.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    from /home/maxycle/code/collaborasound/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-4.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-4.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-4.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-4.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-4.1.3/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-4.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-4.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from /home/maxycle/code/collaborasound/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
    from /home/maxycle/code/collaborasound/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:2:in `load'
    from bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
```

`development.log` does exist therefore this isn't the issue.
As suggested, I have also ran `sudo chmod 0664 /home/maxycle/code/collaborasound/log/development.log` but that didn't help.
Unfortunately I am not skilled enough to fix the problem.

Comment: Seems like an ownership issue, who is the owner of your `collaborasound` directory?

Answer (score 0):

The first error indicates that Rails is unable to access the log file. Make sure the log directory and file have the correct permissions with `chmod 0664 /home/maxycle/code/collaborasound/log/development.log`.

The second error is related to the server.pid file. It seems that the application doesn't have the necessary permissions to write to this file. Fix it with `chmod -R 1777 /home/maxycle/code/collaborasound/tmp`